# How to create Github Bot / Script to look for specific repositories and add git tag as needed

Tags: git, github, git-tag

I'm looking to create a GitHub bot / script that can look through all of the repositories within our organization and for each repo that starts with `ls-`, `is-`, `ms-` tag each with `lrs-wes` if that repository does not already have that tag.

I'm very familiar with Git and GitHub itself as I have worked with both over the years but I am not familiar with writing Git scripts. I have been doing a lot of reading online but am still not 100% clear.

Has anybody created a script similar to this? Or know where I can find an example to help me get started?

Comment: You need to use the GitHub API. I'm not sure if this has much to do with shell scripts and Git commands.

Comment: @mkrieger1 can this process be automated then? So that someone can just run a simple script from time to time to make sure all tags are added as necessary or would it essentially be a set of steps someone would need to follow, based on this guide: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/